# このコードの何が間違えているかわかりません

Tags: python

初めまして！Pythonを勉強し始めてまだ一ヶ月のペーペーの者ですが、このコードの何が間違えているかわかりません。もし良ければ教えていただけないでしょうか？お願いします。

```
def print_hand(hand、name = 'ゲスト'):

    hands = ['グー','チョキ','パー']

    print(name + 'は' + hands[hand] + 'を出しました。')
    

print('ジャンケンを始めます')

player_name = input('名前を入力してください：')

print('何を出しますか？（0: グー, 1: チョキ, 2: パー）')

player_hand = int(input('数字で入力してください')

if player_name == '':
  print_hand(player_hand)
else:
  print_hand(player_hand,player_name)
```

Comment: この辺のヘルプ記事を参考に、動作環境や何が問題なのかについての詳細を追記してください。[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct), [気持ちよく参加するために](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [今日の積み上げ python 学習記録#1](https://qiita.com/umanizer/items/d54e9633f10655fe86d8)

Comment: 質問を投稿する際の書き間違いかもしれませんが、`def print_hand(hand、name = 'ゲスト'):` で関数パラメータの区切り文字が `、`(U+3001) になっています。また、`player_hand = int(input('数字で入力してください')` では `()` の対応が取れていません(`)` が足りません)。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pythonは、indent(字下げ)でプログラムのブロックを表すプログラム言語です。

質問に書かれたプログラムは、適切なindentがされていませんから、質問者が期待しているような動作をしないのだと思われます。

```
if player_name == '':
print_hand(player_hand)
else:
print_hand(player_hand,player_name)
```

というコードでは、エラーなりますよね。

それを、

```
if player_name == '':
    print_hand(player_hand)
else:
    print_hand(player_hand,player_name)
```

というように修正すれば、エラーが出ないはずです。

indentが何なのかとかいうのは、Pythonの本の一番最初、Python言語の文法の説明で書かれているはずですから、まず良く読みましょう。

＝＝＝
質問する際には、質問者が期待していた動作はどのようなもので、実際の動作と何が違うのかが判るように丁寧に説明してください。
何の説明もせずに、「何が間違えているか判りません」って聞いて、答えが返ってくると思いますか？

Comment: インデントの問題は, 質問時に code-block 指定がなく (\`\`\` 〜 \`\`\`) 文章とみなされていたからかも？ (それ直してもインデント少しおかしいけど)